# How to keep python script keep running indefinitely

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping

I made a GUI app from Tkinter in python and want to make such that after a specific time the program runs again and prints accordingly.

```
def check_price():
    name = entry_1.get()
    p = entry_2.get()
    ex_price = float(p)
    usr_email = entry_3.get()
    client_response = Client(name)
    source = client_response.html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    try:
        title=soup.find('span', id ='productTitle').get_text().strip()
        label_4 = Label(root, text=title)
        label_4.grid(row=4, column=0)
    except AttributeError:
        title = "Wrong URL"
        label_4 = Label(root, text=title)
        label_4.grid(row=4, column=0)
        exit()
    try:
        price = soup.find('span', id ='priceblock_dealprice').get_text().strip()
        x="The item is currently discounted at : "+price
        label_5 = Label(root, text=x)
        label_5.grid(row=5, column=0)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            price = soup.find('span', id ='priceblock_ourprice').get_text().strip()
            x = "The product is not discounted currently and Currently the price is : "+price
            label_5 = Label(root, text=x)
            label_5.grid(row=5, column=0)
        except AttributeError:
            x = "Product Unavailable!!"
            label_5 = Label(root, text=x)
            label_5.grid(row=5, column=0)
            exit()
    px = ""
    for ch in price:
        if(ch.isdigit()):
            px=px+ch
    converted_price=float(px)
    converted_price=converted_price/100
    if(converted_price < ex_price):
        send_mail(name, usr_email)
    else: 
        x = "The price is not currently below the price at which you would like to buy"
        label_6 = Label(root, text=x)
        label_6.grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.after(10, self.check_price)
```

So I want that function check_price be called again after 1 hour how can I do so?
I used self.after but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use time.sleep inside a infinite loop with sleep time for one hour or use schedular libraries like sched,schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop and execute it is a background process.

> filename: check_price.py

```
while True:
    check_price()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Run this as a background process.

> nohup python check_price.py &

Comment: I am currently on MacOS and nohup doesn't seem to work

Comment: In Mac - u can use a screen (https://ss64.com/osx/screen.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you must use a while loop, like so:

```
import time

while True:
    # Here goes some additional code if needed

    check_prices()
    time.sleep(60 * 60) #  Time to sleep process / thread in seconds
```

Alternatively, I would recommend starting your programm on OS level, e.g. using a `cronjob` under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the schedule library. you have to `pip install schedule` before using it.

```
import schedule
schedule.every().hour.do(check_price)
```